# Python Pandas - multiply 12 columns by one column to create 12 additional columns

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply

I have a data frame with multiple monthly columns (Month 1, Month 2 ... Month 12) and a currency column (USD exchange rate).

I have different lines with different currency and I would like to create 12 additional columns (and keep my initial columns) that will give converted data (Month 1 USD, Month 2 USD... Month 12 USD).

To do so I have started y work by creating a function:

```
def currency_function(x):
    return test_df['USD Rate'] * x
```

Then trying to apply this function to a list of my columns with an apply and lambda method:

```
cols= ['Month 1', 'Month 2' ... 'Month 12']
test_df.apply(lambda x: currency_function(test_df[cols]), axis="index", result_type='expand')
```

It does not seem to produce what I want to achieve, any tips please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **dict comprehension** to `assign()` with required columns

```
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({**{f"Month {i}":np.random.randint(10,50,5) for i in range(1,13)},**{"USD_rate":np.random.uniform(1,1.2,5)}})

df.assign(**{f"{c} USD":df[c]*df["USD_rate"] for c in df.columns})
```

|  | Month 1 | Month 2 | Month 3 | Month 4 | Month 5 | Month 6 | Month 7 | Month 8 | Month 9 | Month 10 | Month 11 | Month 12 | USD_rate | Month 1 USD | Month 2 USD | Month 3 USD | Month 4 USD | Month 5 USD | Month 6 USD | Month 7 USD | Month 8 USD | Month 9 USD | Month 10 USD | Month 11 USD | Month 12 USD | USD_rate USD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 37 | 21 | 23 | 41 | 12 | 32 | 37 | 19 | 23 | 40 | 44 | 33 | 1.06338 | 39.345 | 22.331 | 24.4577 | 43.5985 | 12.7605 | 34.0281 | 39.345 | 20.2042 | 24.4577 | 42.5352 | 46.7887 | 35.0915 | 1.13077 |
| 1 | 33 | 28 | 26 | 14 | 48 | 37 | 35 | 48 | 17 | 23 | 23 | 44 | 1.13264 | 37.377 | 31.7138 | 29.4485 | 15.8569 | 54.3665 | 41.9075 | 39.6422 | 54.3665 | 19.2548 | 26.0506 | 26.0506 | 49.8359 | 1.28286 |
| 2 | 28 | 22 | 44 | 22 | 15 | 16 | 47 | 15 | 27 | 25 | 32 | 22 | 1.07535 | 30.1099 | 23.6577 | 47.3155 | 23.6577 | 16.1303 | 17.2056 | 50.5415 | 16.1303 | 29.0345 | 26.8838 | 34.4113 | 23.6577 | 1.15638 |
| 3 | 31 | 32 | 43 | 24 | 18 | 22 | 17 | 25 | 16 | 33 | 41 | 25 | 1.05265 | 32.6321 | 33.6847 | 45.2638 | 25.2635 | 18.9477 | 23.1582 | 17.895 | 26.3162 | 16.8424 | 34.7374 | 43.1585 | 26.3162 | 1.10807 |
| 4 | 43 | 23 | 33 | 39 | 36 | 38 | 33 | 32 | 15 | 25 | 29 | 37 | 1.1341 | 48.7662 | 26.0842 | 37.4252 | 44.2298 | 40.8275 | 43.0957 | 37.4252 | 36.2911 | 17.0115 | 28.3524 | 32.8888 | 41.9616 | 1.28618 |

Comment: works perfectly well, if you have 5min to describe a bit the line of code I will be glad.

Comment: using this https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html in python `**{"a":b}` is the same as a named argument `a=b`. i.e. utilising power of `**kwargs`

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you simply use something like this?

```
for col in range(1, 13):
    df[f'Month {col} USD'] = df[f'Month {col}'] * df['USD Rate']
```